# React Router Dom redirect from redux action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am working in a Web application (built using React+Redux+React Router Dom) and Firebase as backend.

My question is: Is possibile to carry out a Redirect from an action creator (so, outside the react router dom components ) ?

For example: I want user to be redirected to Home after an operation of deletion of an item:

```html
export const deleteItem = (item) =>{
  const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var itemRef = firebase.database().ref("users/"+id+"/items/"+item);
  return dispatch =>{
    dispatch({type:'DELETING_ITEM'});
    item.remove()
    .then(()=>{
      // I WANT TO REDIRECT USER TO /HOME (or anywhere else) 
    })
  }
}
```

How can achieve a redirect programmatically ?

Comment: Is you tree wrapped into a `connected-react-router` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

1-) create a history.js file with this content.

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

export default createHistory();
```

2-) in the file you set up Router (in index.js or app.js):
use **Router** from react-router-dom instead of **BrowserRouter**,  import history and give it in history prop of Router like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./history";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

3-) use it in your action

```
import history from "../../history";

export const deleteItem = item => {
  const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var itemRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + id + "/items/" + item);
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETING_ITEM" });
    item.remove().then(() => {
      // I WANT TO REDIRECT USER TO /HOME (or anywhere else)
      history.push("/home");
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use/try this if it's just a simple redirect.

```
export const deleteItem = (item) =>{
  const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var itemRef = firebase.database().ref("users/"+id+"/items/"+item);
  return dispatch =>{
    dispatch({type:'DELETING_ITEM'});
    item.remove()
    .then(()=>{
        window.location.href = url
    })
  }
}
```