# How can I access match.params from within a Redux Thunk action?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-thunk, connected-react-router

How can I do something similar to the below, without manually passing data into the function from a component?

```
function doSomething()
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
       console.log(getState().router.match.params)
    }
}
```

The reason this is important is because vital variables are stored in the URL in React (e.g. page for pagination, document ID, search input). When these are stored in Redux, it's super easy to access them and there's no need to pass them through from a component. But it seems like for match.params, this has to be manually passed through potentially several wrapped components into an action.

Comment: Don't break encapsulation. Put this information in Redux itself, then drive your router and thunks from Redux.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588303/react-router-dom-redirect-from-redux-action-creator/58588534#58588534) answer help?

Comment: @SuleymanSah this doesn't give much more information than getState().router does - i.e. I get the pathname but I think the most important thing I'm looking for here is match (I'll update the question to make this clear).

Comment: The reason match params are important is because important variables are stored in the URL in React, as opposed to in the redux store (e.g. page for pagination, or search input, or document ID). It's super easy to access variables from the redux store in actions, but if I want to access the variables kept in the URL this becomes very complicated and heavy, having to wrap and pass them through a component every time the action is called. This is why I couldn't get help from your suggestions @JoshPittman

Comment: Also yours @GregoryHigley

Comment: My suggestion ecnouraged you to try 'Connected React Router' https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router if you need a deep integration. But it sounds like you just need to reference `window.location` and parse the data you need form the url directly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pass the required params while calling the action.

```
function doSomething(params)
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      console.log(params)
   }
}
// from component
const params = useParams();
dispatch(doSomething(params))
```